# accepts_nested_attributes_for - I18n / gettext translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gettext, rails-i18n

I have this models (Rails 4.2.7):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :pseudonyms, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }, allow_destroy: true
 has_many: pseudonyms
end


class Pseudonym < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :name, :presence => true
   validates :www, :presence => true
end
```

View user/edit:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :pseudonyms do |ff| %> 
    <%= f.form_group :name do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control col-xs-12 ' %>
        <%= f.text_field :www, class: 'form-control col-xs-12 ' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %> 

  <%= link_to_add_association _("add another"), f, :pseudonyms, :class => "btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" %>
<% end %>
```

When I save this with empty name or www I get message:

> Www can't be blank.

I've tried all this combinations (en.yml):

```
    en:
      activerecord:
        models:
          user:
            pseudonyms.name: "Pseudonym"
            pseudonyms.www: "Website"
            pseudonym.name: "Pseudonym"
            pseudonym.www: "Website"
            pseudonyms:
              name: "Pseudonym"
              www: "Website"
            pseudonym:
              name: "Pseudonym"
              www: "Website" 
          pseudonym:
            name: "Pseudonym"
            www: "Website"
          user/pseudonyms:
            name: "Pseudonym"
            www: "Website"
          user/pseudonym:
            name: "Pseudonym"
            www: "Website"
        attributes:
          user/pseudonyms:
            name: "Pseudonym"
            www: "Website"
          user/pseudonym:
            name: "Pseudonym"
            www: "Website"
          user:
            pseudonyms.name: "Pseudonym"
            pseudonyms.www: "Website"
            pseudonym.name: "Pseudonym"
            pseudonym.www: "Website"
            pseudonyms:
              name: "Pseudonym"
              www: "Website"
            pseudonym:
              name: "Pseudonym"
              www: "Website"
```

Without any results. What is wrong please?

I would as well prefer to use gem gettext for the translation, but it's not necessary.

Thanks,
David

Comment: What do you expect it to be? *Website can't be blank*?

Comment: yes, Website can't be blank. @Pavan